# Memory consumption by objects in Java

Tags: java, object, memory, memory-management

I have a question about the memory consumption of an application I'm in the early stages of developing at a university. When I launch a class that extends JFrame that serves as a login manager, the object consumes this much RAM:

[image]

While this JFrame is displayed, the program consumes around 42 MB of memory at any given time. This JFrame allows a user to login and access a medical records system. When the user logs in, the login manager is not simply made to be not visible; it is disposed of with the .dispose() function. The medical records system is then launched.

When the second class is launched (also extending JFrame), the program consumes this much RAM:

[image]

...roughly 66 MB at any given time. This makes sense, as this JFrame object is larger and requires more variables, leading to the object consuming more space. There is a 'log off' button on this JFrame which disposes of the medical records system JFrame object and creates a new login manager JFrame object when pressed.

Intuitively, I would think that because the medical records system was disposed of and the login manager is the only part of the application running, that the memory consumption of my program would drop to 42 MB of memory being consumed at any given time. This is not the case.

The memory consumption of the application remains at 66 MB. When I noticed this, my first thought was that perhaps the .dispose() function doesn't really free up the memory allocated to an object like I thought it did. If this were the case, then repeatedly logging in and out of my medical records system should continuously raise the amount of memory my application consumes as more and more objects are created. However, this is not the case either.

When I logged in and out of my medical records system, the memory consumption of my application stayed around 66 MB. My second thought was that perhaps because the largest amount of memory my application had consumed at one time while running was 66 MB, that the running Java program would hold on to this amount of memory for the duration of its lifespan despite whether it actually needs 66 MB of space or not. This space could then be 'recycled' and used again if the program had need for it. However, this does not seem to be the most efficient way of doing things. If this were the case, a program tasked with sorting an array of millions of elements and using a recursive algorithm such as a merge sort that would take up a large amount of space and then give it back, would be forced to hold on to the largest amount of space consumed by the program at any given time. This would freeze up an unnecessary amount of memory, and doesn't seem like it could be the case.

I tell you all of this so that you can know how I came to ponder these questions: **How does Java handle memory consumption when objects are created and disposed of? How does this apply to my situation in particular?**

Comment: That's the memory reserved by the JVM, it's not necessary fu used by your application. To see actual memory consumption, user a profiler.

Comment: Don't guess, you won't get it right. If you're also just starting with Java, you might want to ignore the whole memory thing for the time being and concentrate on other matters. Memory handling is automatic in Java, but it's not simple. It's easier to understand once you have a better understanding of the Java platform.

Comment: I'm a senior in an Algorithm Design class where we've been studying time complexity and we're about to get into space complexity. I'd like to know more about this topic, and I figured this would be the best place to ask this question.

Comment: @asslyias that would make sense. I'm not familiar with what a profiler is, so I'll do some research.

Comment: I still would like to understand the reason why the observed change in the amount of memory allocated to my application behaves the way it does. I would really like an answer to this question. I'm not just starting with Java; I'm in my fifth year of studying the language and am preparing for graduate study in the near future in the area of computer science. I'm sure someone can answer my question. However, if anyone coming across this knows of a textbook or similar resource I can use to learn more about the JVM, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Like others said before: first you need to use the proper means of detecting memory consumption. You could use Eclipse MAT for this

Comment: Finally, I'd like to state that with regards to the field of computer science, when one makes an observation that one cannot explain for themselves, it becomes necessary to seek further information on the subject. While I agree that reference materials and expert analysis are of utmost importance, I would argue that in lieu of the desired information being readily available one can and should make their own further observations in order to formulate a testable hypothesis (or 'guess'), and to experiment and draw conclusions. @Kayaman, we would be in a far less advanced age without this process.

Comment: @Marged, thank you so much for the suggestion. I'm looking into MAT now.

Comment: @ChristianWestbrook You're not the only one here with a CS degree. I was assuming that you were a mere beginner with Java, considering you're trying to use the task manager to measure memory consumption. Of course 5 years of studying Java in a university doesn't guarantee anything. It can be a harsh reality when you start working and notice that all that beautiful theory doesn't translate to the real world like you'd assumed.

Comment: @Kayaman you're exactly right. Our deeper  analysis of time and memory consumption thus far has dealt with algorithm performance exclusively; nothing specific to one language or platform. I appreciate the advice though, because I've never been introduced to a tool that measures memory consumption.

Comment: Besides the task bar, of course.

Comment: Check out [Visual VM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html) too (it's included in the JDK). It allows for real time profiling of CPU and memory (more coarse grained than MAT though). Then you can get into garbage collection algorithms, and you'll have plenty to read about for a while.

Comment: Sounds great! Thank you again for the two suggested tools. I'll try them out right away and start learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the coments already suggested, you are looking at the wrong number. Basically, Java uses its own memory-management and the ups and downs of your memory consumption can not be monitored using a task-manager or top.

Java allocates memory whenever the current amount of memory is insufficient to handle the task at hand and your memory-parameters (-Xmx) allow it to do so. Once objects are freed within the Java VM, the memory will not be freed by the Java process, but the VM will reserve that memory to be prepared for the next object allocations.

Memory will be freed by a garbage collector. This will be triggered by events like a full memory (or a manual System.gc() call). The garbage collector will identify all objects no longer reachable and free the space, they consume. Free in that case means: for new Java objects, not for the underlying OS. This is the reason why you will typically see an increasing memory consumption throughout a Java execution and virtually none memory reduction. (There is a special case, when the heuristic of the Java VM determines, it has already too much memory allocated and will return it to the OS)

Things are still more complex, as the Java VM manages the memory in a generational model with memory areas for young and old objects seperated from one another. Objects are allocated in the young spaces and grow older with every garbage-collection. At one point, objects are moved from young to old spaces. This is a question of garbage-collection efficiency.

As for observing all of this within a running VM, I will second the proposal of JVisualVM (although I would add, it is for your case only useful with the Visual GC Plugin), but I would also throw JConsole into the ring. For some reason I don't understand, Oracle removed the capability of monitoring old and young memory spaces differentiated in the step from JConsole (the predecessor of JVisualVM) to JVisualVM.

I think your studies will fail if you do not understand the generational memory model of Java and its implication towards overall memory consumption. As a starting point, I would suggest this article: [Understanding the Java Memory Model and Garbage Collection](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-the-java-memory-model-and-the-garbag)